# Uncaught RuntimeError: memory access out of boundsmono_wasm_runtime_ready

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, blazor-hosted

**Note: this problem shows for me even if I create a new Blazor WebAssmebly App, based on target Framework .NET 5.0 and Configured for HTTPS and ASP.NET Core hosted.
Please, to test this case: create an app like that, register a user, confirm the email, and try to log into the app, and type your results in a comment.**

I'm building an application on .NET 5 blazor hosted.

Recently while running the app locally this error started to occur for unknown reasons.

Please have anyone solved it? or we have to wait for .NET 6.

Error: Uncaught RuntimeError: memory access out of boundsmono_wasm_runtime_ready fe00e07a-5519-4dfe-b35a-f867dbaf2e28

Console error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
at get_basic_blocks (<anonymous>:wasm-function[10401]:0x1881b1)
at generate_code (<anonymous>:wasm-function[5264]:0xc7c27)
at generate (<anonymous>:wasm-function[10430]:0x189045)
at mono_interp_transform_method (<anonymous>:wasm-function[1690]:0x31608)
at do_transform_method (<anonymous>:wasm-function[5321]:0xd3578)
at interp_exec_method (<anonymous>:wasm-function[2155]:0x51405)
at interp_runtime_invoke (<anonymous>:wasm-function[7862]:0x12efff)
at mono_jit_runtime_invoke (<anonymous>:wasm-function[7347]:0x118e5f)
at do_runtime_invoke (<anonymous>:wasm-function[3304]:0x79d42)
at mono_runtime_try_invoke (<anonymous>:wasm-function[629]:0x12982)
```

Thnx, JS

Comment: [Review]  There is simply not enough information to wild guess at this.   You need to provide more information.  Out-of-the-box this works.

Answer (score 1):

A problem occurred after installing the Visual studio 2022 preview. once I formated PC it's gone.